# logs to splunk are getting truncated

Tags: splunk, fluentd

I am using fluentd to forward my Kubernetes pod logs to splunk but in splunk I am not able to see full length of pod log as they getting truncated. For example we have a single line log length of 74286 chars, but splunk shows only 16385 chars.
what can I do to overcome this issue ?

This way I have configured in fluentd configmap.

```
<match **>
      @id splunk
      @type splunk-hec
      @log_level info
      server "#{ENV['FLUENT_SPLUNK_HOST']}"
      protocol https
      verify false
      host "#{ENV['CLUSTER_NAME']}_#{ENV['NODE_NAME']}"
      token "#{ENV['FLUENT_SPLUNK_TOKEN']}"
      index "#{ENV['SPLUNK_INDEX']}"
      buffer_type memory
      buffer_queue_limit 256
      buffer_chunk_limit 8m
      batch_size_limit 8000000
      flush_interval 1s
    </match>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Splunk is supposed to truncate at 10,000 characters.  You can change that in your props.conf file.

```
[mysourcetype]
TRUNCATE = 75000
```

This would be in addition to the rest of the "magic" 6 settings: `TIME_PREFIX`, `TIME_FORMAT`, `MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD`, `SHOULD_LINEMERGE`, and `LINE_BREAKER`.

Comment: Anyway to recover truncated log? @RichG

Comment: The truncated data is discarded.  The best you can do is re-ingest, if the source is still available.